# HTML filter not working

Tags: html, search, filter

I buy a website in templatemonster but the filter search not working
( [my website with filter](http://www.thaifold-phuket.hu/guides.html) ).
Example when i choose Italy and press filter button nothing happen, and i don't know what is wrong with it.

HTML filter panel:

```
<!-- Panel-->
              <div class="panel panel-xs panel-vertical context-dark bg-atlantis">
                <h4 class="text-bold">Guides Filter</h4>
                <form class="offset-top-30 offset-sm-top-20">
                  <div class="group group-top">
                    <div class="group-item element-fullwidth">
                      <div class="form-group text-left">
                        <label for="guides-country" class="form-label form-label-outside">Country</label>
                        <div class="select2-whitout-border">
                          <select id="guides-country" name="country" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">All</option>
                            <option value="2">Italy</option>
                            <option value="3">France</option>
                            <option value="4">USA</option>
                            <option value="5">Spain</option>
                            <option value="6">Germany</option>
                            <option value="7">England</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="group-item element-fullwidth">
                      <div class="form-group offset-top-20 offset-sm-top-0 text-left">
                        <label for="guides-sorting" class="form-label form-label-outside">Sorting</label>
                        <div class="select2-whitout-border">
                          <select id="guides-sorting" name="sorting" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">By Popularity</option>
                            <option value="2">By Area</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center text-md-left offset-top-20 offset-sm-top-30">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">filter</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

HTML post:

```
   <div class="cell-md-7 cell-lg-8 cell-xl-9 offset-top-63 offset-md-top-0">
                    <div class="range range-xs-center range-md-left">
                      <div class="cell-sm-6 cell-lg-4">
                        <!-- Guide Post-->
                        <div class="guide-post"><a href="guide-page.html">
                            <div class="guide-post-img-wrap"><img src="images/guides/guide-01-420x280.jpg" width="420" height="280" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block"/></div>
                            <div class="guide-post-body">
                              <div>
                                <p class="guide-post-description text-italic text-gray">Italy</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="offset-top-4">
                                <div class="h4 text-bold text-atlantis">Venice</div>
                              </div>
                            </div></a></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="cell-sm-6 cell-lg-4 offset-top-30 offset-sm-top-0">
```

Comment: As I see, your website's filter working just fine. I typed `italy` and Enter, or just pick item, in the search result. Are you sure that the URL is to **your** site?

Comment: Yes thanks.
But i mean the "Guides Filter" search left side in green box

Comment: Do you know if anyone develop this functionality? It seems that your question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This forum meant to help to people with **specific issues** but not question like "Why it's not working for me"..